# Transfer MySQL database to remote server

Tags: mysql

How do I go about transferring a MySQL database from my localhost to a remote server?  Can it only be done in a command prompt?  Right now, I'm running MySQL 5.1 with a Command Line Prompt and Query Browser.  In SQL Server, you just take the DB offline, copy the .mdf file over, and you're done, but it doesn't seem to be that simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html should be quite helpful.